# Small gap (margin) using Svg and Transform:Translate on some resolution

Tags: html, css, svg, css-transforms

On this example, there's a litte gap under (and beside) the svg that appears only on some resolution for example width of 556px,948px or 1318px (try to stretch window to see)

And it does that only when I use the property transform:Translate ! I have no idea where does it come from...

```css
body{
  background-color:blue;
  margin:0;
}
.two{
  height:150px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}
svg{
  transform:translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="two"></div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 2000 102.3"><title>h-00c</title><path d="M1000,93.12c24,0,516.62,7.94,1000-92.43V102.3H0V.69C483.38,101.06,976,93.12,1000,93.12Z" style="fill:#fff"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome v. 69.0.3497.100

Answer (score 0):

The gap you are saying is actually a SVG. I have changed it's color from white to yellow. Other than that I am not seeing any gap.

```css
body{
  background-color:blue;
  margin:0;
}
.two{
  height:150px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}
svg{
  transform:translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="two"></div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 2000 102.3"><title>h-00c</title><path d="M1000,93.12c24,0,516.62,7.94,1000-92.43V102.3H0V.69C483.38,101.06,976,93.12,1000,93.12Z" style="fill:#ff0"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback but that doesn't change the problem for me.
Check the responsive option on inspector mode, if you move the the width, the gap still apears on specifics resolution.